# Custom shortcode in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a bit stuck and would please like some help if possible:

I have this circle button link with two bits of text in that I wish to make a shortcode:

```
<a href="">
<div class="find-out-btn alignright">
<h3>Header Text</h3>
<p>Paragraph text</p>
</div>
</a>
```

But at the moment I cannot call the function to create it as an actual shortcode - any ideas where I am going wrong?

This is my php so far:

```
// Add Shortcode
function visit_info_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'link' => ‘',
            ’title’ => ‘',
            ’subtitle’ => ‘',
        ),
        $atts
    );

    $link = $atts['link'];
    $target = $atts['target’];
    $title = $atts['title’];
    $subtitle = $atts['subtitle’];

if ($link) {
        return '<a class="visitinfo" href="'. $link .'"><div class="find-out-btn alignright"><h3>' . $title . '</h3><p>' . $subtitle . '</p></div></a>';
    } else {
        '<a class="visitinfo" href="'. $link .'"><div class="find-out-btn alignright"><h3>"Visit"</h3><p>"Find out More"</p></div></a>';
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I link it up to WordPress?

Many thanks,

Comment: WordPress codex is your friend on this. check documentation always. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `add_shortcode` function to set up the shortcode tag you want to use in the editor and link it to your shortcode callback function above, e.g.

```
add_shortcode( 'show_visit_info', 'visit_info_shortcode' );
```

You can add this just before or after your callback function in your functions.php (or plugin file)
This will create the shortcode tag to use in the page editor as `[show_visit_info]`

Reference: [WP documentation for add_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)

Comment: Hi there thank you for that! I just followed a tutorial but it just seems to out put my function on the website and not the content! 

This is my functions.php:
`include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/my_custom_shortcodes.php' );

add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'torque_hello_world_shortcode' );`

And this is the custom .php file

`function torque_hello_world_shortcode( $atts ) {
   $a = shortcode_atts( array(
      'name' => 'world'
   ), $atts );
   return 'Hello ' . $a['name'] . !';
}`

I just get that function printed out for some reason! am I doing something stupid?

Comment: @trailrunner89 Where do you have your `function visit_info_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) `? Add your `add_shortcode` directly before that.

Comment: @trailrunner89 ok, then add it there instead of your functions.php. It goes wherever your shortcode function is

Answer (score 0):

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
//register
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );

echo do_shortcode('[bartag]'); //return foo = something
```

You should read [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)